# Problems getting Singularity Compose to work

Tags: singularity-container

I wrote a small test project for [Singularity Compose](https://singularityhub.github.io/singularity-compose/#/), consisting of a small server application, with the following YAML file:

```
version: "1.0"
instances:
    server:
        build:
            context: ./server
            recipe: server.recipe
            ports:
                - 9999:9999
```

When I call `singularity-compose build`, it successfully builds `server.sif`. Calling `singularity-compose up` also seemingly works without error, and calling `singularity-compose ps` results in something that looks just fine:

```
+ singularity-compose ps
INSTANCES  NAME PID     IMAGE
1        server 4176911 server.sif
```

However, the server application does not work, calling my test client results in it saying that there is no answer from the server.
But if I run `server.sif` directly without compose, everything works just fine.
Also, I tripple checked, my test application listens to port 9999, thus should be reachable from the outside.

What did I do wrong?

---

Edit:
I also checked whether there actually is any process listening at port 9999 by calling `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN`, this is not the case. Only when I manually start `server.sif` without compose it shows me the process listening.

Edit:
I went into the Singularity Compose shell and tried to start the `Server` application directly in there, just as a test, and it resulted in `Permission denied`. Not sure if that means anything.

Edit:
I now gave the application execution rights within the shell and called in there, this works. Am now trying to add execution rights in the recipe. If that works, it would be kind of strange, as the executable was build right there, and thus should already have execution rights.

Edit:
I added `chmod +x` in my recipe both after building `Server` and before executing it. Doesn't work either.

Also checked whether any bridges exist using `brctl show`, this is not the case.

---

Edit: My recipe, adjusted by the input of tsnowlan in his answer below:

```
Bootstrap: docker
From: ubuntu:20.04

%files
    connection.cpp
    connection.h
    main.cpp 
    server.cpp
    server.h 
    server.pro

%post

    # get some basics
    apt update
    apt-get install -y wget
    apt-get install -y software-properties-common

    # get C++ compiler
    apt-get install -y g++
    apt-get install -y build-essential
    apt-get install -y build-essential cmake 

    # get Qt
    apt-get install -y qt5-default

    # compile
    qmake
    make

    ls

%runscript
    /Server

%startscript
    /Server
```

Again, note that the application works just fine both when compiled and startet normally and when started within a Singularity image (but without Singularity Compose).

The `ls` at the end of the `%post` block is used to verify that the `Server` application was build successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Please share the `server.recipe`, as it is difficult to identify should be/is happening without it.

Without having that, my guess is that you have a `%runscript` in your definition file, but no `%startscript`. When the image is executed directly or via `singularity run image.sif`, the contents of `%runscript` determine what happens. To emulate the docker-compose style, the singularity images are started as persistent instances. In this case, the `%startscript` block determines what runs. If it is empty, it will just start up and sit there doing nothing. This would explain why when run by hand it works but not when using compose.

Comment: I don't have a `%startscript` block, so it was probably that. Can't test it now since we switched to another approach and singularity is currently not working (in general, for some other reasons). I'll try to remember your input and might test it in the future.

Comment: Added `%startscript` and tested it, still not working. Added the recipe to my question.

Comment: it worked alright when I ran it swapping out `python3 -m http.server 9999`. what happens when you check `singularity-compose logs`? does it also run manually if you use a clean environment `singularity run -e ...`? Your local env is normally forwarded by default, but probably not by compose